# Association clears when reloading a record in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit

I am only familiar with Rspec, but now I need to fix a library which uses Test::Unit.

I find out that when I reload the record, the association becomes nil

For example:

```
test "accepts nested attributes from subscription to user ()" do
  @user = User.create(name:'Ash')
  @subscription = @user.create_subscription()
  puts "user: " << @user.inspect
  puts "subscription: " << @user.subscription.inspect

  @subscription.update_attributes({ :user_attributes => { :notification_comment => true } })
  @user.reload
  puts "user: " << @user.inspect
  puts "subscription: " << @user.subscription.inspect
  assert @user.subscription, "should have an subscription"
end
```

Outputs:

```
user: #<User id: 815823837, account_id: nil, name: "Ash", email: nil, settings: {}, created_at: "2013-02-07 04:28:51", updated_at: "2013-02-07 04:28:51">
subscription: #<Subscription id: 1, user_id: 815823837, created_at: "2013-02-07 04:28:51", updated_at: "2013-02-07 04:28:51">
user: #<User id: 815823837, account_id: nil, name: "Ash", email: nil, settings: {}, created_at: "2013-02-07 04:28:51", updated_at: "2013-02-07 04:28:51">
subscription: nil
```

Why does this happen? I did check and I can confirm that I can `Subscription.find(@subscription.id)` so it is saved in the database.